# Wireshark not capturing any packets when I apply 'tcp port http' filter

Tags: http, tcp, port, wireshark

I am using a mac and trying to capture packets live packets when I am loading up a website. I am connected over Wifi and am able to capture packets without those filters being used.

However when I enter in 'tcp port http' I am coming up empty handed.

Any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

When you use a port name in a capture filter expression, libpcap (the packet capture library that Wireshark uses) needs to convert the name into a number that it can use to match against bytes the captured packet. It does so by [looking up the port name in `/etc/services`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html). (Specifically, it calls [getaddrinfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo), which usually looks up the port in `/etc/services` on macOS and Linux, and `C:\system32\drivers\etc\services` on Windows.) If I open `/etc/services` on my system here, "http" corresponds to port 80.

However, the modern web doesn't really use port 80 any more. Most web traffic these days is encrypted using HTTPS, and the [IANA-assigned port for HTTPS is 443](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt).

You might have better luck using "tcp port 443" or "tcp port 443 or tcp port 80" to make sure you capture both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: And don't forget that you can verify what port is in use for a filter such as *"tcp port http"* by telling `tcpdump` to dump the compiled packet matching code using the `-d` option.  

You should see that `tcpdump -d "tcp port 80"` and `tcpdump -d "tcp port http"` produce the same output.  Lastly, a shorter form of Gerald's capture filter is, `"tcp port 80 or 443"`, since this is allowed per https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html, which states, *"If an identifier is given without a keyword, the most recent keyword is assumed."*.  The same BPF code is generated either way though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the filter has to be `tcp.port == 80`.

But if your Wireshark doesn't capture anything (without filter), you may check your installation and the [wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup).